# rethrowing exception handled in preceding catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, java-7, rethrow

on oracle ofiicial site write (`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow`)

> In detail, in Java SE 7 and later, when you declare one or more
>   exception types in a catch clause, and rethrow the exception handled
>   by this catch block, the **compiler verifies** that the type of the rethrown exception meets the following conditions:
>
> -The try block is able to throw it.
>
> **-There are no other preceding catch blocks that can handle it.**
>
> -It is a subtype or supertype of one of the catch clause's exception parameters.

Please concentrate on second point (`There are no other preceding catch blocks that can handle it`. )

Research following code:

```
static private void foo() throws FileNotFoundException  {
        try {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

This code compiles good. According my opinion after reading quote from mentioned article I expect to see that compiler will verify it and I will get compiler error.

Did I understand second point wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly fine because the `FileNotFoundException` is derived from `IOException`, and because you go from less specific to a more specific there should not be any issues.

---

edit:

```
static private void foo() throws FileNotFoundException  {
    try {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `throw e;` line, effectively has no other preceding catch blocks that can handle it. It's true that a IOException could be a FileNotFoundException, but not on this particular case. If it were, it would have been caught by the first catch.